# combining categories failure

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, categories

I am trying to combine the heating types categories in my dataset, so that the ones with less than 2000 appears are combined into other. However when I try executing the code, I keep getting this error: "Cannot do inplace boolean setting on mixed-types with a non np.nan value"

I tried the code this way:

```
heats = tidy_housing_cleaned['heatingType'].value_counts()
heating_mask = tidy_housing_cleaned.isin(heats[heats < 2000].index)
tidy_housing_cleaned[heating_mask] = 'Other'
```

Data:
[image: heats]

Error:
[image: error]

Has someone seen this before?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you. **DO NOT** post images of code, links to code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## TypeError: Cannot do inplace boolean setting on mixed-types with a non np.nan value

I suppose that you see this error because there's **more then one column** in `tidy_housing_cleaned`. We can overcome it with `loc`, `replace`, `mask` etc.

### loc

```py
index = heating_mask[heating_mask['heatingType']].index
tidy_housing_cleaned.loc[index,'heatingType'] = 'Other'
```

### replace

```py
tidy_housing_cleaned['heatingType'].replace(
    heats[heats<2000].index, 
    "Other", inplace=True)
```

### mask

```py
tidy_housing_cleaned['heatingType'].mask(
    (heats[tidy_housing_cleaned['heatingType']] < 2000).values, 
    other='Other', inplace=True)
```